# What is the meaning of javascript dispaching events?

Tags: javascript

Dispatching an event means firing it. the following code will fire the click event of the button 2 times.

```js
  let event = new Event("click");
  elem.dispatchEvent(event);
  elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<button id="elem" onclick="alert('Click!');">Autoclick</button>
```

Comment: To dispatch an event means to "fire" it. The handlers listening to that event will be called.

Comment: `$(this).trigger('close')`

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has classes that are listening to the user events (click, hover a button, press a key). That classes are the event dispatchers. What does "dispatch a event" means?

The event dispatchers manage the event in order to "understand" which action has made the user and react with the behaviour that the developer coded.

Javascript has some event dispatcher classes defined by default, but some libraries like JQuery let you create custom events.

To understand a custom event, you can think this example: You are programming a clock class that you will use in the future. You code all the methods to make the clock work. Further, you declare a new event that triggers when a second passes. Let's call it "timestep".

Now imagine you use that class in two different programs. You can implement a different behaviour in both programs by inserting code in the "timestep" event.

In this example, I created a custom event that fires when the user moves one handle. It's behaviour consist in modify the label to the time the handle is on. Check it here:
http://ytcropper.com/crop/hsceS7udV4g